# Potential energy for an amount of time

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, work, potential-energy

a mass of 10kg is maintained at 1m above the ground for 25s. What is the work done during this time interval?

i know this formula :
$ W = F * d * cos(a)$

 but I don't find a formula with the time and i'm sure that if the time was 50s it will be more of work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though the answer given is hinting correct ,I'd say it the other way.

Is the potential energy of the block changing here?
If no,then what do you think will be the work done?
If yes,then how?

Comment: no it don't change because it's the same high along the 25s

Comment: so the work = 0 ?

Comment: Yes! Hope u got it now!

Comment: thank u so much, i get it now :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use the above formula. What is $d$ in this case?

Comment: the gravitational acceleration with the time ?

Comment: like d = 1/2*a*t^2 ?

Comment: This is only the case for a free-falling object. This is not the case here.

Comment: maybe d = g * t so d = 9.81 * 25 ?

Comment: i don't understand the distance because there no displacement

Comment: Exactly. There no displacement

Comment: but i need to compute the distance right ?

Comment: it's d = g * t ?